# IE 7 bug? - prompt save / open when downloading file - c# asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-7, asp.net-3.5, content-disposition

I have an aspx page with linkbuttons that fire javascript to pop open a new aspx page to stream files to the browser for downloading by users.

When developing and unit testing on XP SP3, IE 7 and FireFox 3.5, using the following code (key being the "attachment" part in the Content-Disposition tag), both prompt a dialog box asking if I want to save or open the document, which is exactly what I want to happen:

```
        private void WriteFileToBrowser(Byte[] requestFile, string filename, String m_mimeType, String m_format)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + "." + m_format);
        Response.ContentType = m_mimeType;
        Response.BinaryWrite(requestFile);
        Response.Flush();

    }
```

When I deploy this to a Windows 2003 server and navigate to the same aspx page, FireFox 3.5 correctly asks for a Save/Open option as expected since that is the default operation in FF.

When I navigate in IE 7 however and click to download, i get a pop up window that is visible for 1/8th second tops...and disappears.  No prompt to Save/Open.

If i go into IE 7 -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level -> Downloads

Automatic prompting for file downloads is disabled. When i check it to enable i then get the Save/Open prompt to work correctly.

So my question is.....has anyone gotten a work around to this? I have tried a bunch of things people claim work with different Header tags such as cache, pragma, etc etc...none of that gets around the fact that IE has the download property disabled by default.

Comment: I've tried something similar and it works in IE7,8. Can you provide the exact value of the m_mimeType you use?

Comment: for testing im using this as mime and format in the parameter list

"application/pdf", "PDF"

Comment: Have you try others e.g. application/zip
Something which IE7 cannot display within its window.

Comment: not yet. I call a WCF method to retrieve the bytes and that system is currently only storing PDFs, and they told me they dont have any other file types their software can convert currently.  Lame.

Comment: Microsoft provides IE7, IE6, and IE8 VMs; you could see where the change happened.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into an identical problem recently with our implementation for downloading generated reports in our custom web framework. Research led us to trying the same approach you mentioned (setting Content-Disposition).

The problem is related to IE7 and security zones. By default, certain actions MUST be explicitly initiated by the user. You could start by looking at [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462(VS.85).aspx) and [About Window Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531202(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you would add your page to the trusted sites you would be able to download the file.
While developing all your sites you're running are in this zone.

You can try to force the internet explorer by adding

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

to the end of your request.

Else you could try to post the link to the document, so the browser sees the request as a response of user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to this problem but you need to quote the file name in your output.  Spaces in the file name will screw up the file name when downloading the file.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "." + m_format +"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.TransmitFile("test.pdf");
        Response.End();
    }

Comment: If you see in my example, the file is not from the file system, its a array of bytes im using BinaryWrite() to write to the browser. TransmitFile() will not work in this case unless I assemble the files physically on the system.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a necessity that a new page is opened using javascript, you can use a Response.Redirect() to the aspx page. This should open the save/open dialog.